# Sum of colorvalues of an image

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am looking for a way to sum the color values of all pixels of an image. I require this to estimate the total flux of a bright source (say a distant galaxy) from its surface brightness image. 
Would anyone please help me how can I sum the colour values of all pixels of an image.

For example:
Each pixel of the following image has a colour value in between 0 to 1.
But when I read the image with imread the colour values of each pixel I get is an array of 3 elements. I am very new in matplotlib and I do not know how can I convert that array to single values in the scale of 0 to 1 and add them.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a PIL image, then you can convert to greyscale ("luminosity") like this:

```
from PIL import Image
col = Image.open('sample.jpg')
gry = col.convert('L') # returns grayscale version.
```

If you want ot have more control over how the colors are added, convert to a numpy array first:

```
arr = np.asarray(col)
tot = arr.sum(-1)  # sum over color (last) axis
mn  = arr.mean(-1) # or a mean, to keep the same normalization (0-1)
```

Or you can weight the colors differently:

```
wts = [.25, .25, .5]    # in order: R, G, B
tot = (arr*wts).sum(-1) # now blue has twice the weight of red and green
```

For large arrays, this is equivalent to the last line and faster, but possibly harder to read:

```
tot = np.einsum('ijk, k -> ij', arr, wts)
```

---

All of the above adds up the *colors* of each pixel, to turn a color image into a grayscale (luminosity) image.  The following will add up all the *pixels* together to see the integral of the entire image:

```
tot = arr.sum(0).sum(0) # first sums all the rows, second sums all the columns
```

If you have a color image, `tot` will still have three values.  If your image is grayscale, it will be a single value.  If you want the mean value, just replace `sum` with `mean`:

```
mn = arr.mean(0).mean(0)
```

Comment: Thank you askewchan for your reply. I think, I can not explain my need correctly. I am sorry for that. I actually want to estimate colour of each pixel of the image on the scale 0-1. At this moment, after reading my image with imread I get values of each pixel with an array. Say, I read, d = imread('i.png'). Then I get d[0,0]=array([ 0.27843139,  0.27843139,  0.85882354], dtype=float32). But I want values on the colorbar scale, say d[0,0] = 0.4. Then I want to add the values of d[i, j] (i,j runs from 0 to nrows and ncols respectively), I mean for all pixels.

Comment: You have a color image: The three values that you see when you look at one pixels (`d[0,0]`) are the values of the Red, Green, and Blue channels.  If you want to have a single value for each pixel you must somehow add or average the three color channels together to make one channel (grayscale/luminosity).  I've shown you a few ways to do this.  The weighted (`wts`) version gives you the most control over how the colors are added/averaged.  I've added a section at the end of my answer to show you how to add up all the _pixels_ once you have made the image grayscale (single-channel).

Comment: It seems like your image is still color.  How did you convert to grayscale?  Did you save the result?  You cannot just do `im.convert('L')`, you must do `im = im.convert('L')`, or save it to another name like `gray = im.convert('L')`

Comment: Sorry! you are right. The image was not converted to grayscale before. Now I get it correctly, I think. Please check the way I do it. im=Image.open('i.png'), arr=np.asarray(im), tot=arr.sum(-1), F1 = tot.sum(0).sum(0). I get F2 for another source. Then I do F1/F2. Please let me know I am correctly doing it or not.

Comment: Since you are adding all the colors then adding all the pixels, you can just do `tot = arr.sum()` and it will add _all_axes at once.  Otherwise, looks good to me!

Comment: Thank you very much. Your last suggestion is the fastest solution. Everything is done!

Comment: Glad to help :)  Keep in mind that adding the three colors together might not be the wisest thing to do --- the different channels might need different weights depending on the application.  Astronomical brightness is not the same as png's RGB scaling.

Comment: Yes, I am again in void. The result I get is completely wrong.

Comment: Maybe you should use the mean of the colors, and the sum of the pixels: `tot = np.einsum('ijk,k->', arr, np.ones(3)/3.)`

Comment: Actually my brightness scale is min = 0, max = 1.189e-15 for one source and min=0, max = 3.938e-18 for the other. I thought if I do (F1*1.189e-15)/(F2*3.938e-18) it will give me the brightness ratio since the png colorscale are on 0-1. But the result I get is wrong. Would you please spend some time more about this and let me know how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Does this help?  `(F1*1.189)/(F2*3.938e-3)` Using such small numbers could mean numerical inaccuracy.  Otherwise, it could be that `F2` comes from a different method of converting color to grayscale.

Comment: Nope. If I make the both colourscale same will that solve this? I am trying to do that now.

Comment: Yeah, try that. At least that way they'll be comparable to one another.